# #1305 - FUNCTION omediain_joom442.JSON_decode does not exist

Tags: mysql

I am using shared hosting with `MySQL version 5.6.43` and getting error:

```
#1305 - FUNCTION omediain_joom442.JSON_decode does not exist
```

earlier i tried with JSON_extract but that is not supported.

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  idx,
  JSON_decode(cb_contactgroup, CONCAT('$.cb_mobile[', idx, ']')) AS fishes
FROM jost3_comprofiler
  -- Inline table of sequential values to index into JSON array
JOIN ( 
  SELECT  0 AS idx UNION
  SELECT  1 AS idx UNION
  SELECT  2 AS idx UNION
  -- ... continue as needed to max length of JSON array
  SELECT  3
  ) AS indexes
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(cb_contactgroup, CONCAT('$.cb_mobile[', idx, ']')) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY rec_num, idx;
```

Could someone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON support was added in MySQL 5.7, your server is 5.6.43.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

The JSON functions available are documented here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html